# Figuring out how to make a Discord Bot send a DM in Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to add a command to my Discord bot that sends confidential information through DM's. This is what I currently have:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(name='password', help='DM's you your password')
async def on_message(message):
    await member.create.dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send('password')
```

The problem I keep getting is "name 'member' is not defined". I have tried replacing member with Member, user, and User, but I have not gotten through. I have even tried to make the bot just send a DM with this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def DM(ctx, user: discord.member, *, message=None):
    message = message or "This Message is sent via DM"
    await bot.send_message(user, message)
```

but it still raises the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

CTX has a property of message which has a property of author which can be used to send a message directly.

So the person who is triggering the command, will be ctx.message.author.

Also I don't think that pass_context=True is necessary, but I could be mistaken.

```
@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx):
    return await ctx.message.author.send("Henlo Werld!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `send_message`, it's very [old version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) of discord.py.
So, first of all - update your discord library - `pip install -U discord.py==1.4.2`.

Your question has answer at [Frequently Asked Questions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm)

For future help, I recommend joining the [Discord support server](https://discord.gg/dpy)

Happy coding!